# Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift

I was attempting to port the `firechat-ios` project over to Swift and ran into some issues. I suppose this might just be requiring the firebase folks to make some update to their SDK, but I figured I would ask anyway. I wasn't able to successfully build my project after adding Firebase and its dependencies.

I get a warning:

```
ignoring file /Users/n/Projects/SwiftChat/Firebase.framework/Firebase, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/n/Projects/SwiftChat/Firebase.framework/Firebase (3 slices)
```

and two errors:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Firebase", referenced from:
>         __TFC9SwiftChat14ViewControllercfMS0_FT7nibNameGSQSS_6bundleGSQCSo8NSBundle__S0_ in ViewController.o

And

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

any ideas?

Comment: There is [a thread on the mailing list that may help](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/m7vDEdF_lf4). Joe wrapped Firebase.h by creating a "bridging header" to include it in swift without the required build setting, which is not part of the Firebase SDK yet.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Hm, I'm going to take another stab at it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: ... there's also a guy on that thread reporting the same issue as me (now i don't feel quite as dumb) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working. It turns out that the video on the firebase website which explains which dependencies to include was out of date. I read further down the page and saw that firebase actually needs two dependencies that I was missing.  After adding `libc++.dylib`, `libiucore.dylib`, `CFNetwork.framework`, `Security.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework` everything worked fine.

Comment: Great work! Please consider adding your findings to the mailing list as well, so I don't have to plagiarize them :)

Comment: The list of dependencies has been updated: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/alternate-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try temporarily removing arm64 under Projects: Build Settings: Valid Architectures.

This should not be considered a permanent solution, but may get you going until Firebase update their SDK.

Comment: the missing architecture is not the _arm64_, it is _x86_64_, which may be the simulator instead of a real device.

Comment: Fair point. In that case, building on a real device and only building the active architecture should work around it. Of course, this requires a device running iOS 8.