# Can't import Firebase framework into iOS 8 Swift-based *framework*

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, swift, firebase

I am trying to create a swift-based iOS 8 framework, and wanted to include Firebase framework into it. The [instructions on Firebase site](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) are only for importing Firebase into iOS **apps**, which uses bridging headers. Per [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_79), bridging headers don't seem to apply to a Swift **framework** importing an Objective-C framework. I was looking at the *Importing External Frameworks* section on the Apple link. It specifies that: "When you import an external framework, make sure the Defines Module build setting for the framework you’re importing is set to Yes."

Despite that, I tried to manually create bridging header and adjusted Swift Compiler - Code Generation Building Settings, to no avail.

Would you know if the Firebase framework has *Defines Module* build setting set to Yes? If it does, then I'll keep digging into why I get "Use of unresolved identifier Firebase" after explicitly following Firebase instructions a few times. I am using Xcode 6 Beta 5. Any other suggestions and work-arounds are also deeply appreciated.

Here is a work-around I tried, that did **not** work:

In Xcode 6 Beta 5, I created a new Objective-C framework - SwiftFirebase. In it, I

1. imported Firebase framework, and the other five frameworks
2. set the -ObjC flag
3. copied references of all the .h files in Firebase Headers folder into the new framework - SwiftFirebase.
4. made those references from Project to Public
5. imported  into the SwiftFirebase umbrella header
6. ensured that Defines Modules was enabled. It was, by default.
7. Build for Running.

Created a new Swift-based Framework: TestFramework to test the above SwiftFirebase, where I

1. Added SwiftFirebase from Debug-iphonesimulator into the new library
2. Created a new swift class
3. Imported SwiftFirebase
4. Added an init method, where I put in the sample swift code from Firebase quick-start.
5. Build for Running
6. Got an error compiling: "Firebase/Firebase.h not found"

My guess is that copying references of header files from a Firebase into another Objective-C framework and making them public is not an effective way of manipulating files. :)

Hate to wait for Apple's fix. Anything else I could try? Did I miss something in the above steps that you could think of? Many thanks!

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093463/firebase-with-swift?rq=1 ?

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I did check that one. It is related to missing two frameworks from the list of five that Firebase requires. I have all of those already imported. My question is about importing Objective-C frameworks into a Swift framework. To recreate my issue, I opened Xcode and created a New > Project > iOS > Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework, specified Swift as the language, and then ran through all the steps that Firebase recommends.

Comment: @GST Did you have any luck with it?

Comment: Had a similar problem, but it was solved after MANUALLY creating bridging header and including <Firebase/Firebase.h>. Weird, but worked for me.